# convert degree within a range

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to work out how I can convert an angle to a number range.

for example if I have a max value of **38** and a min value of **10** and I want to convert that angle between the min and max.

Any idea how I would go about that?

Thanks

Comment: could you share a few more details? For example: How does your code look like? What kind of user input are you talking about? I don't really get your question...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to convert degrees (d) whose range varies from (0 - 360), to a number range (a1 - b1). Suppose `rng = b1 - a1`, so the value of the number, say x is `a1 + (d * rng) / 360`.

If any doubts please comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help that was exactly what I needed